# Limiting Date Range in R when Plotting

Tags: r, plot, date-range

I was trying to plot two columns of my `data.frame` (let's call them `data$Date`, `data$x` for convenience).

When plotting `data$x` I want to limit myself to data from after `2014-01-01`. What's the proper way of doing that?

Comment: For convenience, could you make your example reproducible?

Comment: Reproducible [like so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first put your `Date` column as Date with `strptime` and then subset your data.frame to keep only dates post 2014-01-01:

```
data$Date <- strptime(data$Date, format="%y%y-%m-%d")
plot(data$Date[data$Date > strptime("2014-01-01", format="%y%y-%m-%d")], data$x[data$Date > strptime("2014-01-01", format="%y%y-%m-%d")], las=1, pch=19, xlab="Date post 01/01/2014", ylab="")
```

**Example**

```
 data <- data.frame(Date=c("2013-02-03","2013-12-13","2014-02-02","2014-05-05"), x=1:4, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

[image]

***EDIT***
If you need to plot more than one "`x`", you can first use `plot` and then `points`. You can adjust the `x axis` with `axis.POSIXct`:

```
data <- data.frame(Date=c("2013-02-03", "2013-12-13", "2014-02-02", "2014-05-05", "2015-04-14"), x1=rep(1, 5), x2=rep(2, 5), stringsAsFactors=F)
data$Date <- strptime(data$Date, format="%y%y-%m-%d")
plot(data$Date[data$Date > strptime("2014-01-01", format="%y%y-%m-%d")], data$x1[data$Date > strptime("2014-01-01", format="%y%y-%m-%d")], las=1, pch=19, col="red", xlab="Date post 01/01/2014", ylab="", xaxt="n", ylim=c(0,3))
points(data$Date[data$Date > strptime("2014-01-01", format="%y%y-%m-%d")], data$x2[data$Date > strptime("2014-01-01", format="%y%y-%m-%d")], pch=19, col="blue")
axis.POSIXct(1, at=seq(strptime("2014-02-01",format="%y%y-%m-%d"),strptime("2015-04-01",format="%y%y-%m-%d"), by = "month"), format = "%m/%y")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, CathG. How can I add a key to the plot (in case I have more than one parameter)?

Comment: @Dinosaur, you're welcome. Sorry but I don't understand what you mean by "add a key to the plot", what parameter you have that can be more than one, can you give me an example to help me better understand what you mean ?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. For example, if I want to plot data$x1 in red and data$x2 in blue against data$Date on the same graph, how can I indicate which graph is which? Also, how could I adjust the "nodes" on the x-axis? At the moment, I only have two on the x-axis, "2014" and "2015". Thanks again for your help!

Comment: you can first plot `data$x1` with `col="red"` and then use `points` to plot `data$x2` with `col="blue"`. As for `x axis` you can plot it with `axis`. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your data frame stores the date as a standard date type, you can also set the xlim option in plot using the date type, e.g.:

```
xlim<-c(as.Date("20140101","%Y%m%d"),as.Date("20180801","%Y%m%d"))
plot(data$Date,data$x,xlim=xlim)
```